# edit faq sections that are not question definitions?

Tags: support, faq-update-request, site-faq

[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) beta just got the new theme.  The [FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy) still has the Sketchy section asking "why does this site look sketchy".  We're not sketchy any more, but I don't see any link to edit it.

[image]

Is there a way to edit parts of the FAQ other than the question definition section, or does it come from a centralized (beta) boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the FAQ should be removed, or changed to something similar to "Why is this site using a generic theme?" as the theme using in a beta site is not the definitive one the site will use when it graduates.

The FAQ comes from a boilerplate that is common to all the beta sites. The only part moderators can edit is the "What kind of questions can I ask here?" section; the other sections of the FAQ cannot be edited.

Comment: Gotcha...  I suppose I'll wait until the rest of Betas are off sketchy before expecting a change.